# Android Emulator: Google Play Services tab hanging on loading

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I've recreated emulators to see if it makes a difference, I've attempted to start with a lower Andriod version on a different device, both Arm and X86 architecture emulators - but each has this problem.

The outcome I'm hoping for is maps working on an android app (which works on a physical device), just not on any emulator on my machine.

Even if I update Play Services from inside the store, this Loading state doesn't change - also the map doesn't show up on the app - which is said to be caused by play services (I've got a API key for google maps in the app, again it works on a physical device).

[image: Hanging on loading]